# How does laravel know the value of request()->getHttpHost()

Tags: php, laravel, http, hostname, tinker

If I SSH into a server running a laravel app and run in the tinker command line:

```
print_r(request()->getHttpHost());
```

This tells me the domain name of the server. But how does it know? Where is this information stored. What does it query to get this information. And why doesn't it return "localhost" or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel will first look at the `X_FORWARDED_HOST` HTTP header. If this header is not available, it will look at the `HOST` HTTP header.

If neither of those headers are available (i.e. when using the command-line) it will look at the `SERVER_NAME` configuration variable. Finally, if the server name is also not available it will return the value of the `SERVER_ADDR` configuration variable.

You can read the source of `Request::getHttpHost` [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.3/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1009).